# Daily average for orders

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a sheet of data, with quantities of 1 in one column for each order, and then one column for the date of the order. Is there a way to write a formula that gives me a daily average of orders? Here's a link to my sheet for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ezg5-puWet3tY8kQRFutlhrJH8Lak1Kb0eQ_SiXqzUQ/edit#gid=0

Same question for monthly average as well!

Comment: Are you looking for the Sum of Quantity (Column B) for each unique date (Column D)?!

Comment: Apologies! I want to add up all the quantities in Column B for the rows that have the same date in Column D. ie. if I have five rows with quantities of 1 and dates of mar 2, with ten rows of quantities of 1 and dates of mar 3, ideally I want a formula that gives me the daily average of 7.5

Comment: Can you enter in the ideal expected output(manually calculated) for the sample data in your sheet so that it gives us a clear picture to work it out.

Comment: and then eventually the same thing applied to column C instead of D, where I can find monthly averages for all quantities (col B), ie if march had quantities of 30, and feb had 20, one formula that gives me a value of 25

Comment: alright I updated the 'Data' tab to have two values I'm trying to solve for, the daily average (in this simplified case = 2), and the monthly average (in this case = 3)

Comment: QUERY Average group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may test these out:

***Daily Average:***

```
=round(average(byrow(unique(filter(D2:D,D2:D<>"")),lambda(Σ,sumif(D:D,Σ,B:B)))),2)
```

***Monthly Average:***

```
=round(average(byrow(unique(filter(eomonth(D2:D,),D2:D<>"")),lambda(Σ,sumif(index(eomonth(D:D,)),Σ,B:B)))),2)
```

[image]